# What is the MS Access equivalent of Uncommitted read (WITH UR - DB2 or NOLOCK - MS SQL)

Tags: ms-access, db2

I have a bunch of DB2 linked tables in my access database. These are from the production environment and the read queries (select) I'm running is apparently messing with production jobs.

Is there an uncommitted read equivalent that I can use in access to run the queries? I know that I can use Toad and it allows me to use WITH UR in the SQL query but I cannot import my whole project mid flight to Toad and hence it would be nice to have it done in Access.

Comment: will `WITH UR;` not work on the query you are running? (either through code, or through the MSAccess Query builder)

Comment: Sean, I've tried adding WITH UR to my SQL code and it gives me an error and doesn't let me run with those key words. I don't know if I'm doing it correctly but I have been able to run it with Toad without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Access uses ODBC to connect to DB2 (or at least that's how we do it in my shop), you could change the [ODBC settings to use the correct transaction level](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0008832.html).

You should be able to go to your ODBC settings panel (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC)), and configure the source in there. (Go to your DSN -> Configure -> Advanced Settings)

Then, as mentioned in the article above, for `UR` (Uncommitted Read), you'd set `TxnIsolation` = 1